# Word that means prejudice re humans and robots

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, "racist" refers to prejudice for/against a particular human race, and "speciesist" has been suggested for referring to bias for/against a particular animal species.

What would be a appropriate term for referring to a bias for/against robots vs human beings?

(I'm guessing that some terms have achieved at least minor currency in sci-fi and such terms would be reasonable suggestions.)

Usage:  I simply want to refer (in a jocular fashion) to myself as being XXXist for not wanting to allow robots to "go where humans go" (taking "go" to mean "use the bathroom").

Comment: Why not "robotist" if the tone is jocular? I don't believe there is a word that fits this use, but you're plenty free to make one up as you please.

Comment: @RMac - I'm hoping for something that implies a little more prejudice, and, similar to "racist", which doesn't explicitly identify "which side you're on".  And I want a word that folks will understand without having to explain it.

Comment: You'll have a problem finding a word that fits the pattern of your examples. For instance, "racists" belong to a race and fear or hate other races. "Sexists" belong to a sex and fear or hate other sexes. Is there an identifying quality you would say applies to both a robot?

Comment: I'm giving a thought to "RURacist".  Though it would of course confuse many with low blood sci-fi content who would take it to mean "are you racist".

Answer (score 1):

Ideas for a human prejudiced against robots: Biological chauvinist, bio-chauvinist, biological supremacist.